# Before I use AVAudioPlayer play a linkUrl, I want know the linkUrl is valid

Tags: ios, url, avaudioplayer

Before I use  AVAudioPlayer play a linkUrl, I want know the linkUrl is valid...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=392285&uk=2117415770"];
NSData *voiceData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to check if file exists at server or not

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:5.0];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

    __autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                          returningResponse:&response
                                      error:&error];
    if (error)
        DLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)",
             NSStringFromClass([self class]),
             NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
             [error localizedDescription],
             [error localizedFailureReason]);
    else
    {
        if ([response statusCode] == 404)
        {
            NSLog(@"File Doesn't exist");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"File exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: YES,You are so strong ,and its very user for me,thanks very much!!

Comment: If there is any kind of file related to URL then this works definitely.I haven't checked it for all urls.